# Scraping data from E-Commerce Websites

Tags: web-scraping

Is it possible for me to scrap all the reviews for a particular product from this website ?
The format must me customer name,review made by the customer,rating,Date

https://www.flipkart.com/moto-e3-power-black-16-gb/product-reviews/itmekgt2fbywqgcv?pid=MOBEKGT2HGDGADFW

if so please help me through this process !!!

Comment: Yes, you can but in which language. And what you have tried yet.

Comment: I have tried using Data miner Scraper extension in chrome but i could retrieve only the  reviews nothing about the customer and rating .. Also tried import.io and failed too